# how to insert into table using jdbc, when there are compound keys

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table with attributes `(id, language_id, genre_name)`. `genre_name` gets names in two languages, and `id` and `language_id` are part of the primary key. How to make 'insert' new values using JDBC(preparedStatement,(java.sql.Connection) Connection), so, `id` can be the same for `language_id` automatically ?
For example:

```
id | language_id| name                    |
1  |      1     | name in one language    |
1  |      2     | name in another language|
```

P.S.
`id` is auto-incremented.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think there is something special to do? If this is about having an automatically generated identifier which is shared (as opposed to you specifying it), then please say so explicitly in your question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I thought, insert it manually. Defining id and language_id

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I have a jsp form, which needs to fill it

Comment: I recommend you read a [basic tutorial on using JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insertion through JDBC is pretty straightforward. You have to connect your database (which you haven't named), then create the `PreparedStatement` through the data that you need (which means you should have the `language_id` and `name` before hand).

This would be a rough example:

```java
String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO genre(language_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test", "postgres", "password");
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT)) {

    preparedStatement.setInt(1, YOUR_ID_COMES_HERE);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, YOUR_NAME);

    int row = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    // rows affected
    System.out.println(row); //1

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is an example with Postgresql, but if you search on google how to perform insertion with java JDBC, you will have a lot more resources than this.